# Why disconnecting one outlet kills power in other outlets?

Tags: switch, receptacle

I am having trouble connecting a switch to a switched outlet. When wires on the outlet are disconnected like in the picture below, the power disappears in all outlets in the same room as well as in some downstairs.

[image]

When both of the black wires on the outlet are connected to its lower half and the red outlet wire is connected to the upper half, both halves get 120V no matter what position the switch is in. A continuity test shows that both red (1) and black (2) wires from the outlet each connect to wires 1 and 2 like they connect with each other somewhere inside the house. Is it supposed to be like that? When I run a continuity test on the other black outlet wire (3), I don't find any wire in the switch that would connect to it. Also, that wire is not hot.

[image]

What I want is the lower half of the outlet to be always hot and the upper part to be controlled by the switch as I have wired a ceiling fixture to the upper half. What is the proper wiring to accomplish this?

Comment: Some questions that would need some answers before proceeding?

Comment: a) Was this outlet the existing one? Was it previously always powered top and bottom?

Comment: b) Is that switch freshly added? If not what was its original function?

Comment: c) Did you pull that cable that contains the red wire? If not what how was that red wire originally wired before you started changing things?

Comment: d) Have you inspected the outlet to see of the shorting bars that connect the top and bottom sides are still present or are broken off on one side? Do you understand what those breakaway shorting bars are for and how they are meant to be deployed?

Comment: @MichaelKaras We just moved into the house, and both the switch and the outlet were already there. The outlet was originally controlled by the switch. I didn't pull any cables. I am just trying to replace the switch and the outlet, and I was stupid enough not to take a picture of how the wires were connected prior to disconnecting them.

Comment: @MichaelKaras And yes, the shorting bars are broken off on the side of the red/back cables. I also used a multimeter to make sure there is no connection between the two broken parts.

Comment: Well in addition to some more clarification needed on my other questions..... e) Why did you need to replace the switch if it already controlled the outlet? f) As I understand it you wanted to plug that new lighting fixture into the switched outlet. Why did this require replacement at all if the existing outlet was already switched?

Comment: @MichaelKaras The switch and the outlet had to be replaced because they were old and ugly. Their replacement has nothing to do with the lighting fixture.

Comment: You may want to check some of the other outlets. Possibly more than one in the room was switched and the red wire daisy chains from the switch location to another outlet and then to the outlet that you have opened up. If there is another "switched" outlet possibly it never had it's breakaway shorting bar removed.

Comment: @MichaelKaras How can I check if another outlet was switched?

Comment: Open all the other outlets and see of any of the boxes have the red wire cable coming in and then exiting the box.

Comment: @MichaelKaras Good call! I found another switched outlet in the room, and its breakaway shorting bar wasn't removed. So my wiring was correct in the first place. I just needed to remove that bar. Feel free to post your suggestion as an answer, and I will be happy to accept it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The evidence gleaned from your question and the conversation in comments strongly suggests that the shorting bar between the top and bottom half of a "partial switched outlet" has not been removed. If it has been already removed from the outlet that you have open then there is a strong possibility that there is another switched outlet on that circuit.

The cable in the switch box with the red wire may very well daisy chain to another outlet box before eventually terminating at the outlet box that you have open. Check all other outlets on that circuit to see if you find a box with the red wire cable both entering and leaving the box. Good chance that the shorting bar at that location has not been removed.

Answer (score 0):

The silver colored screws, on one side, are where the neutral conductor goes.
The gold colored screws, on the other side, are where the hot wires land.

By default, the upper and lower screws do not correspond to the upper and lower half of the outlet. In order to separate the upper and lower halves, there should be a small metal tab between the gold screws which can be snapped off.